# How to capture all the data of a dynamic list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm scraping a list that changes over time
the problem is that:
As new values ​​are added the old ones are hidden.
so I need to continue the list but only if the sequence is not in it as you can see in the pictures

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I got the first list
then I tried to get the index where the new list differs from the previous one
then add to the first list the new list from the generated index.

```
def achar_ind(lista: list, nova_lista: list):
    inds: list = []
    ind: list = []
    for i in enumerate(nova_lista):
        for k in lista:
            if i[1] == k:
                if not ind:
                    ind += [i[0]]
                else:
                    if ind[-1] + 1 == i[0]:
                        # print(f'**********************\t{i[0]}')
                        ind += [i[0]]
                    else:
                        inds += [ind]
                        ind = [i[0]]

                break
    inds += [ind]
    return inds
```

```
def add(lista: list, nova_lista: list):
    a: list = []
    a += max(achar_ind(lista, nova_lista), key=len)
    return a[-1]
```

```
grafico += [x for x in novo_grafico[add(grafico, novo_grafico)+1:] if len(novo_grafico) - 1 != add(grafico, novo_grafico)]
```

Comment: Are the values unique ? They look like it in the examples you provided, it would simplify the problem, but I guess they are not.

Comment: It reminds me of the [Longest common substring problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem). Otherwise, we need a treshold to determine if values are new or not. How many values typically have changed between two scrapings ?

Comment: @ Lenormju, their are generated randomly, so not unic
sometimes they appears repeatedly twice ou three

Comment: @Lenormju, it depends, but this cannot be the focus because sometimes there is a problem with the internet connection and I have to repeat and continue from where I left off. The range wouldn't the same